# Spring one error for multiple fields

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have a question about validating if multiple form fields are empty and returning one error message for all of the fields

For example lets say I have a Customer entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="middle_name")
private String middleName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="ssn")
private Integer ssn;

@Column(name="phone")
private Long phoneNumber;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Integer getSsn() {
    return ssn;
}

public void setSsn(Integer ssn) {
    this.ssn = ssn;
}

public Long getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(Long phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

And I have a Spring form to do a search by either First Name, Last Name, or SSN like that goes like this:

```html
<form:form method="get" modelAttribute="customer" action="submitCustomerSearch" >
   
   First Name:
   <form:input type="text" path="firstName" name="firstName"/>
   <br>
   
   Last Name:
   <form:input type="text" path="lastName" name="lastName"/>
   <br>
   
   SSN:
   <form:input path="ssn" name="ssn"/>
   <br>
   
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"><br>
   <form:errors />
  </form:form>
```

Now I would like to display an error message in a div right underneath the form saying something like,

**"Please enter at least one search criteria.  you may not leave all fields blank."**

in the case that the user hits submit with an empty form.

Now my main question is that how do I handle this in the backend by using either a controller or Spring Validation?  I tried messing around with Spring form validation API, and came up up with something like this which works out for me.

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) target;
    if(customer.getFirstName().isEmpty() && customer.getLastName().isEmpty() &&
            customer.getSsn() == null ){
        errors.reject("empty.form");
    }
}
```

Although this will work, I don't prefer doing this, because it doesn't seem like an elegant way of returning an error message.
The reason being is lets say I were to change my form to have up to 10 fields for my search instead of 3, then I would have to include 10 checks in one if statement instead of 3.

If anyone has a better way of returning a global error without condensing this into one if statement in the validator then I would really appreciate it!

Also here is a snippet of my Controller method and other relevant methods:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

...

@Autowired
CustomerValidator customerValidator;

...

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setValidator(customerValidator);
}

...

@RequestMapping(value="/customers/searchCustomer")
public String searchCustomer(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    return "searchCustomer";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/customers/submitCustomerSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String submitCustomerSearch(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    customerValidator.validate(customer, result);
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "searchCustomer";
    }
    Set<Customer> custs = customerService.getUniqueCustomers(customer); 
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("custs", custs);
    return"redirect:/customers/searchCustomer";
}
```

The Service getUniqueCustomer(customer) only calls the DAO method so I am not gonna post anything from the service, but here is the DAO method.

```
public Set<Customer> getUniqueCustomers(Customer customer){
    Criteria crit = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
    if(!customer.getFirstName().isEmpty())
        crit.add(Restrictions.like("firstName", "%"+customer.getFirstName()+"%"));
    if(!customer.getLastName().isEmpty())
        crit.add(Restrictions.like("lastName", "%"+customer.getLastName()+"%"));
    if(customer.getSsn() != null)
        crit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("cast(ssn as varchar) LIKE '%"+customer.getSsn()+"%'"));

    return new LinkedHashSet<>(crit.list());
}
```

Comment: I think my question is being misunderstood.  I do not want to learn validation in general. I already know how to do that.  I am trying to figure out the best way to return a global error for a form where at least one field is required and not all fields can be empty or null.  For this I want only one error message saying somthing like "Please enter at least one search criteria. you may not leave all fields blank."